# Part of speech: "early"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

What part of speech is *early* in "I had my lunch early"?

Is it an adjective or an adverb?

Comment: I think it's General Reference that *"I had my lunch **early**"* is an adverbial usage, and *"I had an **early** lunch"* is an adjectival usage.

Comment: As such this would be a good question at English Language Learners because it pertains to learning English, plus no research efforts are shown.

Comment: And who cares, anyway? In English the distinction is almost useless unless you specify more, like "temporal adverb". Time words behave differently from other adverbs, and they're not the only special group. Learning to identify "The Eight Parts of Speech" in grammar is about as elementary and useful as learning to identify eight different plants or animals in biology. Kind of irrelevant for grownups, really.

Comment: In any case, don't ask for a fish, learn to fish. You think it's an adjective? Try replacing it with another adjective. You think it's an adverb? Replace it with another adverb. This question is too localized as is.

Comment: @JohnLawler: why not give your comment (or an elaboration on it) as an answer?  “The classification you’re using is out-dated and inaccurate; here’s a more meaningful classification” is a very useful answer to a question like this; and moreover, such an answer takes it beyond general reference, since most standard references simply say that it’s an adverb.

Comment: @RegDwight: Trying your suggestion; *"I had my lunch cold"*: so it must be an adjective. *"I had my lunch recently"*: so it must be an adverb.

Comment: There you go. A clear decisive answer. As for making it an answer, I've said it many times here already. No point in making yet another Official Answer about it. Plus, I can't anymore cause it's on hold until the appropriate forms are filled out.

Answer (score 2):

The word *early* can certainly be used as an adverb of time (See [Adverbs of Time list](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/adverbs-time.htm))

If it feels strange to you to call it an adverb, just try replacing it with a more "familiar" adverb

> I had my lunch quickly.

It's an indication of how the verb *had* was carried out.

Comment: And what's wrong with the reasoning that in this sentence, you can also replace *early* with a more "familiar" adjective? *"I had my lunch cold".*

Comment: @PeterShor I guess the distinction can be made by asking which sentence answers the question *How was your lunch?* and which one answers the question *How did you eat your lunch?*

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an adverb in this case. To use it as an adjective, you can say

> I had an early lunch.

Comment: 'I got up early in the morning' . Here it is ?

Comment: adverb. @Shivani_S

Comment: A good answer should provide an explanation, plus external links are encouraged.